# Depolyment of express app on vercel takes forever

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vercel

I'm trying to deploy my repository to Vercel using the following GitHub repository: https://github.com/piotrjass/VercelServer.

In my package.json, instead of using parcel build, I've used npx parcel index.html for the build command.

When I initiate the deployment process on Vercel, it starts building, and I get the message "✨ Built in 35ms". However, the building process then takes around 10 minutes before I eventually cancel the deployment.

What could be causing this delay in the building process, and how can I troubleshoot and resolve it?